# Numbering Grid Rows in Ext JS Ext.grid.panel

Tags: extjs, grid

I am trying to get numbered rows with my grid.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',
    {
```

I looked into the documentation for Grids in Ext JS, however, I cannot find a numbering property. Any ideas for me?

Here's my columns section. The info in the columns is pulled from a server.

```
columns:
        {
            xtype: 'rownumberer',
            defaults:
            {
                align: 'center',
                flex: 0,
                width: 40,
                sortable: false,
                menuDisabled: true
            },
            items:
                [
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`RowNumberer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.RowNumberer) column type.

Edit:

You must add **an extra column of this type**. Example:

```
Ext.widget('grid', {
    columns: {
        defaults: {
            // you column defaults
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'rownumberer' // this is a column type
        },{
            dataIndex: 'foo'
            ,text: 'Column Foo'
        },{
            dataIndex: 'bar'
            ,text: 'Column Bar'
        }]
    }

    // ...
})
```

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work. Here is my columns section.

Comment: You must add a column for rownumberer, I updated my answer with an example.